# In react.js after ajax call and render third party script (Not component) not effecting rendered html like Owl-carousel effect on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, dom, owl-carousel

I am trying to use owl-carousel in react.js. 
But after ajax call I get photos to render owl-carousel slider in html the owl-carousel not effect the div to make it proper slider.

I have tried many things.
1.I tried to load that owl-carousel js file. It load but did not work.

This Code I tried to load owl-carousel js file after ajax call and rendered html.

```
const script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = base_url+"/frontEnd/js/owl.carousel.min.js";
script.async = true;
$('footer').append(script);
```

Its not giving any error message

Comment: you could use this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-owl-carousel

Comment: I solved it. Actually I don't wanna use package.
By the way Thanks Brother